# 10001 paypal internal error: timeout processing request Express Checkout

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

First of all, i dont have a Bussiness Account, so if that is the problem, just tell me, because is almost impossible to find where is the requeriment for Paypal Express Checkout in their official website.

My code for this API is:

```
$requestParams = array(
     'METHOD' => $method,
     'VERSION' => $this -> _version,
     'USER' => $PayPalApiUsername,
     'PWD' => $PayPalApiPassword,
     'SIGNATURE' => $PayPalApiSignature
);

$request = array_merge($requestParams, $params);
//$params is bringed from other php.

$ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL ,'https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp');
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_VERBOSE ,1);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER ,false);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST ,false);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER ,1);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPGET ,true);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS ,$request);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

Then, until here is (i think) all right. But doing some checks this is what i sent with $request:

```
$request: array(16) {
["METHOD"]=>
string(18) "SetExpressCheckout"
["VERSION"]=>
string(4) "97.0"
["USER"]=>
string(27) "xxx_api1.example.com"
["PWD"]=>
string(16) "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy"
["SIGNATURE"]=>
string(56) "zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz"
["RETURNURL"]=>
string(50) "http%3A%2F%2Fwww.website.com%2Fcontinue.php"
["CANCELURL"]=>
string(53) "http%3A%2F%2Fwww.website.com%2Fpaypal%2Fcancel_url.php"
["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT"]=>
string(5) "10.95"
["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE"]=>
string(3) "EUR"
["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT"]=>
string(5) "10.95"
["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID"]=>
string(24) "xxx%40example.com"
["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION"]=>
string(4) "Sale"
["L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0"]=>
string(17) "ProductA"
["L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0"]=>
string(5) "10.95"
["L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0"]=>
string(1) "1"
["L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0"]=>
string(1) "1"
}
```

And this is what i receive from Paypal:

```
$response: 
TIMESTAMP=2013%2d01%2d07T23%3a20%3a43Z
CORRELATIONID=7a8130fb32e44
ACK=Failure
L_ERRORCODE0=10001
L_SHORTMESSAGE0=Internal%20Error
L_LONGMESSAGE0=Timeout%20processing%20request
```

Does anyone know what is happening here? Is this wrong? Is the premier Account the problem here?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

I solved this problem with this:

**AVOID** using **"urlencode()"** to encode the params, save your data as normal.

example:

```
array(
   'RETURNURL' => 'http://www.yourwebsite.com/confirm.php', //without urlencode()
   'CANCELURL' => 'http://www.yourwebsite.com/cancel.php'  //without urlencode()
);
```

**USE http_build_query($request)** in the moment before sending it via "Curl" like this:

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS , http_build_query($request));
```

Comment: `http_build_query($request)` did it for me

Comment: holy shit, this is a bug in paypal's handling of the "multipart/form-data" encoding.. and after 3 years

Answer (score 0):

You don't by any chance have your return urls as a subdomain with an underscore in them do you?

Comment: well, is a normal website like http://www.yourwebsite.com/PP_confirm.php and /PP_cancel.php. Is this symbol "_" a problem?

Comment: I found my development domains were getting some really obscure errors from paypal because I was using a subdomain with an underscore e.g. my_subdomain.example.com

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error however my problem was the wrong format of card expiry date. The error I was receiving was being caused by the date that I was passing over. It was not in the correct format. It needed to be ""032018" not "3/2018".